# How can I determine which OpenGL methods cause fallback to software rendering?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, fallback

I am writing an OpenGL (ES) application, and my device seems to fall back to software rendering.  How can I determine what API calls/device restrictions are causing this to happen?

In my case, this is happening on a Raspberry Pi with OpenGL ES 2.0, but an ideal answer should apply to a much wider range of OpenGL versions and OSes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I honestly do no think there is a proper way to find out.

The graphics card drivers will provide functionality for a certain version of OpenGL, as far as I know it does not have to provide hardware support for those features, just be able to handle your application requesting them. So a card could claim support for say OpenGL 4, but almost everything that is newer then OpenGL3 could be simply software rendered.

You might be able to find some documentation for the hardware you wish to run on that will tell you what is hardware accelerated. Failing that, you may have to simple try to build up the list of features you use slowly until you start seeing it has fallen back on software rendering.

Also, how do you know it is using software rendering, is it just the performance hit? I guess it could be possible that whilst it does support a feature in hardware, it does so very badly. There is also the possibility you are not creating your context correctly in the first place, thus can't take advantage of the more recent version.

Comment: Erg.  Well, this is distressing.  If your answer is correct (as it probably is), then I am in quite a bit of a pickle.  I'll give it a few more days to see if anyone else has an answer, and if not then just toss you the bounty.

Comment: thecoshman is correct.  As compared to DirectX which (used to) provide a query for what's hardware accelerated, OpenGL took the different route that all features would be supported, but there was no guarantee for performance.  In fact, in earlier days, various combinations of state settings may have caused the driver to move from hardware acceleration to software support.  You get that much less when using a shader-only version of OpenGL nowadays, but the situation has been somewhat rekindled with OpenGL ES and embedded hardware.

Comment: It is a shame really, I would have thought it fairly reasonable to have a standard feature the query support for certain features. It's a valid thing to want to do in my opinion, allows you to fall back to lower quality but still faster techniques thanks to at hardware acceleration. As I understand it, this is roughly how extensions work, except 'core' features are guaranteed to at least have software level support. There *might* be an extension that can do what you are after, but you can't say for sure how widely support it would be.

Answer (score 3):

if device supports GL_ARB_debug_output then debug output might have clues whether something is software rendered or bad for performance.

Usage is described in the document http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/debug_output.txt
In short you should set log buffer or callback function that would receive messages.

There is also another one debug extension http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/KHR/debug.txt probably some more exists.

to use KHR extension you should init context properly

```
EGLint ctx_attribs[] = {
EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
EGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_KHR, EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_DEBUG_BIT_KHR,
EGL_NONE};

EGLContext *ctx = eglCreateContext(dpy, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, ctx_attribs);
```

and setup callback

```
static void on_gl_error(enum source, enum type, uint id, enum severity, 
sizei length, const char* message, void *userParam)
{
    printf("%s\n", message);
}

static void enable_debug_callbacks(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS_KHR, GL_TRUE);
    glDebugMessageCallbackKHR(on_gl_error, NULL);
}
```

Others probably work in similar way, you should check supported extensions before trying this, this is done by examining return of the call. It is a string with list of all supported extensions.

```
glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
```